# Javax.swing and Java.awt clashing

Tags: java, swing, awt

Im having a problem with all my code involving gui.
For example the `public class Ritpanel extends Jpanel` line gives me an error:

> getBaselineResizeBehavior()' in 'javax.swing.JComponent' clashes with
> 'getBaselineResizeBehavior()' in 'java.awt.Component'; attempting to
> use incompatible return type`

he quick fix is to implement method which do nothing. I have also tried to reinstall IntelliJ. Does anyone know whats wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*; import java.awt.*;

public class Ritpanel extends JPanel{

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics grafik) {
        super.paintComponent(grafik);
        grafik.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        grafik.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
        grafik.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        grafik.fillRect(200,0,60,500);
        grafik.fillRect(0,200,500,60);

        String text = "SVERIGE!!!!";
        grafik.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Font font = new Font("Times new Roman",Font.PLAIN,36);
        grafik.setFont(font);
        int bredd = grafik.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(text);
        grafik.drawString(text,500/2 - bredd/2,470/2 + 24/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use your IntelliJ to import each method individually.

Comment: You can import on the classes you need. In this example `import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;` instead of `import javax.swing.*`

Comment: Still doesn’t work. The highlighted code is still marked red and gives the same error message. Forgot to mention that I can run the program without any problem. It’s just annoying with the error message and it could effect my grade.

Answer (score 1):

How about importing only the things you need?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

Also, sometimes the highlighter highlights errors or warnings that aren't there. Try cleaning your project and rebuilding it.

Comment: Just adding the required imports doesn’t work and it’s not only this project it’s for all projects and classes using swing ant set. I did some digging however and the problem seems to be in the JComponent class for swing. 

The getBaseLineResizeBehavior method gives me two error messages. First: Incompatible types. Found: ‘java.set.Component.BaselineResizeBehavior’, required: ‘java.awt.Component.BaselineResizeBehaviour’. Second: Cannot access java.awt.Component.BaselineResizeBehaviour.

Comment: @pontuswesterfors just for reference, I don't get any warnings or errors when I copy-paste your code into my Eclipse 2020-12 with JDK 15 installed.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem seemed to be a bug in my swing. My solution was to delete all settings and plugins. Then I completly reinstalled IntelliJ. This solved my problem and I no longer get this error.